# which algorithm should i use to change/modify the curves

Tags: iphone, quartz-2d, cgpath

I have made an application which draws a number of curves, using UIBezierPath. Now I'm trying to implement a modification functionality in it. To modify the particular curve one thing I can do is to draw all the curves again; I have not yet implemented this. But I think this algorithm would not be very efficient when the number of curves increases because I have to store all the points in the array and I have to run for loop to draw each curve every time I go for modification.

I am looking for more efficient algorithm. It will be helpful if someone can provide example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent individual curves as `UIBezierPath`s and draw them separately by creating one `CAShapeLayer` per curve and assigning the shape layer's `path` property to the corresponding `CGPath` property of the bezier path. To update an individual curve, you then just have to manipulate one bezier path and the corresponding shape layers `path` property.

Comment: I understood.Do u have any links to tutorial or sample code? It will be more helpful.

Comment: You may have a look at http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-4 and Google around a bit.

Comment: I implemented using CAShapeLayer. While modification i can not remove the old path. Anothe problem is i can not grab the CAShapeLayer from the UIView. It is like once you draw and put on UIView you can not change its contents. Instead you have to make a new CAShapeLayer.Any idea ?

Comment: Just keep a reference around to the `CAShapeLayer`, and set its `path` property when you are done modifying the path.

Answer (score 0):

Redraw the curve until you have a performance problem as measured with Instruments. If that occurs again use Instruments to pinpoint the best way to optimize.

It is easy to get sucked into spending time on optimizations that are never needed. Initially it is much better to put that time and thinking into creating a "clean" code.

Comment: I am looking for another algorithm which is less cumbersome. I need ideas on inbuilt properties of CGPath which i am not aware of and can be useful to me to implement my functionality.

Comment: With your question it is hard to help with that, not knowing what kind of changes you expect to make or how many points (10 or 10000). I am drawing a curve with over 100 points, updating by tracking finger movement and there is no perceived redraw time issue.

Comment: The main issue is i have drawn more than one curve and than i join them. I want to change the particular curve without affecting others. And to do this i can do one thing is to redraw all the curves. What you exactly do when you redraw the curve ?

Comment: Have you considered drawing several path segments and then joining them with `- (void)appendPath:(UIBezierPath *)bezierPath
`? Then you can change one of the path segments and just re-join them.

Comment: I have not used the     -(void)appendPath:(UIBezierPath*)bezierPath But if using this i can change the individual path than it will be helpful.

Comment: i implemented appendpath. But how will i grab the path which i want to redraw?